# Unable to list or open files in Android Documents directory

Tags: android

So I've used Excel on my phone to create a file called `theBook.csv` that has been saved to the phone's `Documents` folder. When I try to list the contents of the phone's `Documents` folder, I get a `NullPointerException`, saying that I have attempted `to get length of null array`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Documents";
// I have also tried:
// String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
// and
// String path = Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Documents";
Log.i("Files", "The path is: " + path);
File f = new File(path);
File file[] = f.listFiles();
try {
    Log.i("Files", "Number of files: "+ file.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
        Log.i("Files", "Found file with name:" + file[i].getName());
    }
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    entoast("NPE"); // my toast message method
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I view the log, the value of `path` is `/storage/emulated/0/Documents` (regardless of which of the three lines I try), and I'm unsure if that corresponds to the `Documents` folder where `theBook.csv` lies. If it does, why isn't `theBook.csv` being displayed in the log files? If not, how do I get my program to access the actual `Documents` folder of the phone rather than just an empty directory?

The Documents folder is viewable when the phone is connected via USB for file transfer, and is also vieable when using the file browser built into the phone. I am running Android 6.0 on my phone, although the app's minimum required SDK is Android 4.1. I have the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` line in my manifest file as well.

Comment: You have to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in your manifest file.

Comment: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE comes under dangerous category permission you should request permission run time. This feature is added in  Android 6.0

Answer (score 0):

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE comes under dangerous category permission you should request permission run time. This feature is added in Android 6.0.

To check permission is granted or not

```
// Assume thisActivity is the current activity
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

If the app has the permission, the method returns PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED, and the app can proceed with the operation.Other request permission run time.

For more details , visit android official document

[Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

For complete list of dangerous permission https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

Comment: I will definitely be taking a look at requesting permission during runtime. Meanwhile, would there be a more optimal external storage directory for the app to look into that's not the Documents directory?